# Phonegap - DeviceReady event not working - Not sure if the script gets loaded properly

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Below is my markup in index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="Styles/Style.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src ="Scripts/MyScripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">Hello</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And Below is my script

```
window.onload = function () {
    alert("test");
};
$(document).ready(function () {

    alert("test2");
});

document.addEventListener("deviceready", "OnDeviceReady", false);   

function OnDeviceReady()
{
    alert("test3");
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "hello world";

}
```

I built the app using Phonegap build and tested it on android phone. The alerts in the first two functions are working fine, but the callback function for deviceready is not working. I'm am not sure if cordova.js is loaded correctly.

I downloaded phonegap and copied the config.xml and cordova.js from the following folder locations

```
\phonegap-2.9.1\phonegap-2.9.1\lib\android\cordova.js

\phonegap-2.9.1\phonegap-2.9.1\lib\android\example\res\xml\config.xml
```

I haven't made any changes to the config.xml yet. Could anyone please help me with my issue ? I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a string as event handler and not the function. Try:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", OnDeviceReady, false);
```

Comment: Just a quick question, if I need to access camera or contacts, do i need to make any changes to the config.xml ? Will i be able to use the api functionality by just calling the phonegap api's methods on myscript.js ? -Thanks

Comment: I think, since you use Phonegap 2.9 there should be no need to edit the config.xml for that purpose.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you do need to add a few lines to your config.xml with phonegap 2.9. Look at the features - usage: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml